# Convert .xlsx file to html using NPOI

Tags: apache-poi, npoi

I want to convert .xlsx file to html using NPOI. Is this possible? I know , xls to html conversion is available using NPOI. But not sure if NPOI provide option to convert .xlsx file to html also. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ExcelToHtmlConverter`. It has method `ProcessWorkbook` which accepts `IWorkbook` as a parameter. So it can be used to convert either `HSSFWorkbook` (xls) or `XSSFWorkbook` (xlsx).

```
public void ConvertXlsxToHtml()
{
    XSSFWorkbook xssfwb;
    var fileName = @"c:\temp\test.xlsx";
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        ExcelToHtmlConverter excelToHtmlConverter = new ExcelToHtmlConverter();

        //set output parameter
        excelToHtmlConverter.OutputColumnHeaders = false;
        excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenColumns = true;
        excelToHtmlConverter.OutputHiddenRows = true;
        excelToHtmlConverter.OutputLeadingSpacesAsNonBreaking = false;
        excelToHtmlConverter.OutputRowNumbers = false;
        excelToHtmlConverter.UseDivsToSpan = true;

        //process the excel file
        excelToHtmlConverter.ProcessWorkbook(xssfwb);

        //output the html file
        excelToHtmlConverter.Document.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "html"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. for some reason when i am converting my xlsx file using above code i am getting "Illegal IndexedColor index: 0" exception . is there any fix for this?

Comment: It's hard to say. I've tried this with simple xlsx file. How does your xlsx file looks like? I will test it.

Comment: @shashank I can't download it. The file has been deleted

Comment: can you please help me on" Illegal IndexedColor index: 0" exception

Comment: please help me on this. Really stuck . I want to convert excel files to html without opening excel in any UI

Comment: @shashank as I wrote in another question the error with Illegal IndexedColor index:0 is a bug in NPOI library and I have no idea when it will be fixed

Comment: Hi how to get the RawHTML from that object excelToHtmlConverter?

Comment: or maybe save that Raw HTML to memory stream?